# Parsing images from a remote server to android client

Tags: android

### I have been doing some research on How to parse images in android

---

*I found this tutorial which is really great & well written*

[***`TUTORIAL LINK`***](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-json-parse-images-and-texts-tutorial/)

- I am dealing with JSON parsing for images
- This involves using a `image loader` to parse the images
- Is this a good way to parse images when we are dealing with a
  database of thousands of images

---

1. I also read about intent service for dealing with images
2. what are the pros and cons of `image loader` & `intent service` ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I use to do that :

1. I got a php file wich resquest the databse and get all images URL
2. Ths php file return me a JSON
3. I use an AsyncTask into my android Class and call the remote php file
4. Parse the JSON into a JSON Array
5. Foreach URL found, add it into a List
6. Use another AsyncTask to retrieve image from the URL like that :

   private class DownloadImageTask extends AsyncTask {
           ImageView bmImageLoad;

   ```
       public DownloadImageTask(ImageView bmImage) {
           this.bmImageLoad = bmImage;
       }

       protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
           String urldisplay = urls[0];
           Bitmap mIcon11 = null;
           try {
               InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
               mIcon11 = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
           } catch (Exception e) {
               Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
               e.printStackTrace();
               this.cancel(true);
           }
           return mIcon11;
       }

       protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
           if(result != null) {
               bmImageLoad.setImageBitmap(result);
           } else {
               bmImageLoad.setImageResource(R.drawable.loading_picture);
           }
       }
   ```